# Eliminate common rows from two tables - MS Access

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, duplicates

I have two tables that have the same structure:

```
'NCC Code' - Integer
'Vendor' - Short Text
'Profit Center' - Short Text
'Business Franchise' - Short Text
'Business Division' - Short Text
'Spend' - Float
'Savings' - Float
```

These tables contain different sets of data, coming from two different sources. There are some rows that are identical in both, but most are different. The difference is not the same for all rows, it's not in the same column (Ex: some records can differ by 'Business Franchise' and all the other columns are identical, others by 'Savings' and otherb by more than one column).

There is no unique value or key in each of the tables as they come generated from the DWH system.

As far as software tools go I only have access to MS Access 2013 and MS Excel 2013.

I need to find a way to identify and extract all the rows from one table, that are not found in the other. Could anyone give me an advice on how to do it? I've tried various methods but to no avail.

Thank you!

Comment: Access supports a LEFT JOIN.  Join all columns FROM A to all columns B.  Then only display those where B is NULL.  This would give you all records in A not in B.

Comment: Thank you. This join will compare the whole row from A to the whole row from B to determine if there is a duplicate or not?

Comment: Yes, but a union all may work as well with an aggregrate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a LEFT JOIN  (only displays those in A not b but you could switch the table order and union the results to get both)

```
SELECT * 
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
 on A.Col1=B.Col1
and A.Col2=B.Col2
and A.Col3=B.Col3
and A.col4=B.Col4...
WHERE B.Col1 is null
UNION ALL
SELECT * 
FROM B
LEFT JOIN A
 on A.Col1=B.Col1
and A.Col2=B.Col2
and A.Col3=B.Col3
and A.col4=B.Col4...
WHERE B.Col1 is null
```

USING a UNION ALL and an AGGREGATE : This would display records from either table not in the other (A not in B and B not in A)  The union all doesn't distinct out the duplicates (union does a distinct) We then exclude records having more than 1 occurrence.  This assumes that each table doesn't have any duplicates in it to start with.  If they do we could just make it a Distinct for  table before the union all.

and then aggregating

```
SELECT <All Columns less src), max(src) as SrcTable, cnt(1)
FROM (SELECT A.*, 'A' as src
     FROM A
     UNION ALL 
     SELECT B.*, 'B' as src
     FROM B ) C
GROUP BY <All Columns less src>
HAVING count(1) < 2
```

I added src so we knew which table the record came from.  max(src) works because  the record only exists in one place. and we exclude those in both.

Answer (score 1):

I made it and I want to post this because there might be others encountering the same problem. It seems that MS Access is very strict about paranthesis. If you want to run a join query and one of the conditions includes a string field, you should put all conditions between paranthesis like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
 on (A.Col1=B.Col1)
and (A.Col2=B.Col2)
and (A.Col3=B.Col3)
and (A.col4=B.Col4)...
WHERE B.Col1 is null
UNION ALL
SELECT * 
FROM B
LEFT JOIN A
 on (A.Col1=B.Col1)
and (A.Col2=B.Col2)
and (A.Col3=B.Col3)
and (A.col4=B.Col4)...
WHERE B.Col1 is null
```

For me also worked if I put all that follows ON between a single set of paranthesis:

```
SELECT * 
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
 (on A.Col1=B.Col1
and A.Col2=B.Col2
and A.Col3=B.Col3
and A.col4=B.Col4...)
WHERE B.Col1 is null
```

A bit of extra info here: 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/15c36745-f7a4-4926-9687-7161e5894468/join-expression-not-supported-error-caused-by-unbracketed-join-expression-comprising-string?forum=accessdev